# Error while inserting array and JSON into PostgreSQL using Codeigniter 3.1.10

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a project which uses Codeigniter 3.1.10 framework and PostgreSQL as database. and I am passing a form value from controller to model like the following:

```
$data = array(
   'field1' => $value1,
   'field2' => $value2,
   'field3' => $value3
)

$result = $this->modal->function_insert($data);
```

where value 1 is string, value2 is an array and value3 is JSON. I am trying to insert data to PostgreSQL. In table, data types are correctly defined which are respectively text, text[] and jsonb.
While in modal my code goes like this:

```
public function function_insert($data)
{
   $result = $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
}
```

I am getting the following error from codeigniter:

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: database/DB_driver.php
Line Number: 1471
Backtrace:
```

And the query shows like this:

```
INSERT INTO "table_name" ("field1", "field2", "field3") VALUES ('1', Array, Array)
```

Is there any issue in my code, data that I pass to model or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to direct insert of PHP Arrays into the database. You have to do some tricks like in the below examples.

**1. For inserting PHP Array into Postgres Column value of type Array**

```
 $phpArray = [1,3,3];
 $pgColValue  = '{'.implode($phpArray,',').'}';
 echo $pgColValue;
 //outputs
 {1,3,3} // Treated as postgres array
```

**2. For inserting JSON.** Use PHP built in function name `json_encode()` for conveting `PHP` array to `JSON` string.

```
$phpArray = [1,3,3];
$pgColValue  = json_encode($phpArray);
echo $pgColValue;
//outputs
[1,3,3]
```